# Persist multiple objects at one go

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0, hsqldb

My current project uses JPA and HSQLDB.

I would like to persist multiple related objcts at one go, is that by any means possible in JPA?

Ex: Suppose there are two entities like `Person` and `ContactInfo`, where Person has `List<ContactInfo>` entities.

If I want to persist `Person` entity along with `ContactInfos` also, what I am doing is set the list in Person and call persist. Will doing that take care of persisting `List<ContactInfo>` also? (With foreign key reference to Person ID in database table)

Else kindly let mek now how would I achieve this in JPA.

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will, if you set `@*ToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: Hi Bozho, can you also let me know how to get a transaction in JTA mode because if I use EntityManager, it throws IllegalStateException. Or could you let me know how to get a connection in JTA mode? Hould that be via JNDI lookup?

Answer (score 1):

You could do as Bozho suggested, but if you would also like them to be updated, deleted, etc. when it's done with Person, I would suggest to cascade like that:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

**Note**: orphanRemoval will only work with JPA 2.